# WPF DataGrid SelectedItems Not Working on Production

Tags: wpf

WPF Code

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1" xmlns:data="clr-namespace:System.Data;assembly=System.Data"
        xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"

        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <my:tst x:Key="tst" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="grdDataTable"
                        CanUserAddRows="False" 
                        CanUserReorderColumns="False" 
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        SelectionMode="Single"
                        IsReadOnly="True"
                        CanUserResizeColumns="False" 
                        Margin="10" AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
                        SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedRow,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DtCollection, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}">

            <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Row.RowState}" Value="4">
                            <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Background" Value="Aqua"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Row.RowState}" Value="16">
                            <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Background" Value="AntiqueWhite" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>

                <DataTemplate>
                    <DataGrid x:Name="InnerGrid" Height="80"  HeadersVisibility="Row" 
                              DataContext="{Binding Path=ItemsSource, ElementName=grdDataTable}"
                                         Background="DarkGray" 
                                          CanUserAddRows="False" 
                                          CanUserReorderColumns="False" 
                                          CanUserResizeColumns="False" 
                                          CanUserDeleteRows="False" 
                                          CanUserResizeRows="False" 
                                          CanUserSortColumns="False"
                                          Margin="-8,5,0,0" 
                                          AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
                                          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedRow,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                          Tag="{Binding Path=ItemsSource, ElementName=grdDataTable}">
                        <DataGrid.ItemsSource>
                            <Binding ElementName="grdDataTable" Path="SelectedItems"                                      
                                     UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"  />
                            </DataGrid.ItemsSource>
                    </DataGrid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code Behind

```
namespace WpfApplication1 {
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;

    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged 
    {


        private DataTable dtCollection=new DataTable();
        public DataTable DtCollection
        {
            get
            {
                return this.dtCollection;
            }
            set
            {
                this.dtCollection = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("DtCollection");

            }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            LoadTable();
            this.grdDataTable.DataContext = this;


        }

        private void LoadTable()
        {
            DtCollection.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            DtCollection.Columns.Add("Add1", typeof(string));

            DtCollection.Columns.Add("Add2", typeof(string));

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                DataRow dr = DtCollection.NewRow();
                dr[0] = i.ToString();
                dr[1] = (i * 10).ToString();
                dr[2] = (i * 100).ToString();
                DtCollection.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
        }

        // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event 
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

The above code works fine on the development machine. I deployed the
changes to production but once I select the row on the top grid
nothing is visible at the bottom grid. I am quite confident this is
some binding issue but cannot install any software on the production
to check. Only difference between production and development that
development has 4.5 version of .net but production has 4.0. though I
have developed my code under 4.0. Once the value in the below datagrid is edited parent row value should be changed immediately. Everything working fine on my local machine. The reason I am using datagrid inside my datatemplate as I need to do all the validation and my cols are dynamic.

I have wasted my whole day today to resovle this, due to limitation of time immediate answer will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid to tell you that the only person who can fix your problem is you. Showing us your code won't help because we can't reproduce your problem with it. All problems like yours can be solved in the same way. You basically need to find out the values of your various objects as the program is running. You clearly can't debug the production version, so you'll have a bit more work to do to find out the values.

There are two main ways... the first and easiest is for you to add a whole load of calls `MessageBox.Show` that alert you to the values of your various objects. This is ok if you can test without the end users having access to the application. If they do, then you'll need to add some sort of logging, that will save the values to the database or a text file, that you can view after running the application.

Once you know the values, you'll be able to work out what is going wrong. The chances are that it has something to do with permissions, or maybe incorrect file paths.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I know the problem the actual problem is the InnerGrid datagrid does not Bind with the specified ItemSource. I need to look for any other option to bind the inner Grid with the selectedItems source from the parent grid. I can bind with the selectedItem instead of SelectedItems but the value in the parent grid is only updated on lost focus of the Inner Grid.

Comment: If your application was written in .NET 4, then it will run in .NET 4, regardless of whether .NET 4.5 is installed on the client or not. I don't think that that is your problem. However, if you think that it is, then try declaring a class that implements the [`INotifyPropertyChanged` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) and making your collection of type `ObservableCollection<YourClass>`. Then simply iterate through the `DataTable.Rows` collection populating the collection of your classes.

Comment: The parent Grid is populated without any issue. Only problem is on production when the parent datagrid row is selected for some reason InnerDatagrid is not binding selectedItems to the Itemsource. Tomorrow I will attach few Images to make it more clear.

Comment: I uninstalled .Net 4.5 and face the same problem, if my application is running under v4.0. This is really shocking for me. I assume when we install v4.5 it updates few of the dll's in the 4.0 directory

Comment: Why is that shocking for you? I told you that yesterday.

Comment: It is other way around when I installed .NET4.5 it updated few core dll's and hence my code works fine if .net 4.5 is installed even though my code was written in .NET 4. what you mentioned "If your application was written in .NET 4, then it will run in .NET 4, regardless of whether .NET 4.5 is installed on the client or not"