# Very simple binding of an object list to a ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

Given the following, how do I have only the DeviceName property show up in the DeviceListBox?

```
namespace NotMyNS
{
    public class Device
    {
        public int SerialNumber { get; set; }
        public string DeviceName { get; set; }
    }
}

namepace MyNS
{    
    public partial class myControl : UserControl
    {
        public ObservableCollection<NotMyNS.Device> DeviceList { get; set; }
    }
}

<UserControl x:Class="MyNS.myControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">    
    <Grid >        
        <ListBox Name="DeviceListBox" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I have looked at many examples but haven't been able to adapt what I saw to my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set [`ItemsControl.DisplayMemberPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to the property that you want to display from your view model. Also if you want to use `DeviceList` as `ItemsSource` you need to specify binding context to be `UserControl`

```
<ListBox 
   ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DeviceList}" 
   DisplayMemberPath="DeviceName" />
```

Comment: Your code almost works for me. If I leave out the DisplayMemberPath, I get items in the ListBox, but they are of the form "NotMyNS.Device".  I am assuming that DeviceName is defined as public string DeviceName { get; set; }   It might not be, it could be simply public string DeviceName;  Would that cause an issue with DisplayMemberPath?

Comment: Yes it matters. It must be a public property and won't work with a field. Can you confirm if it's field or property?

Comment: No, NoyMyNS is a namespace from a 3rd party dll. So I cloned Device into myDevice in which I used properties and I got my DeviceName in the ListBox as advertised (so I can assume the dll used fields).

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `DisplayMemberPath`:

```
<ListBox Name="DeviceListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding DeviceList}" DisplayMemberPath="DeviceName"  />
```

Comment: Ok, that compiled...  I was apparently seriously over-thinking the ItemsSource Binding. I was attempting to use static resources and all sorts of other ideas.    DeviceList starts off empty and events add things to it.  Those added items are not appearing on the screen even tho I am using an ObservableList.  Do I have to do something to refresh the ListBox?

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything unless you're replacing the `DeviceList` property, in which case you'd need to signal that the property has changed through the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.  How are items being added?

Comment: Like this (because the event that adds the device is on a different thread) :  DeviceListBox.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => DeviceList.Add(device)), null);

Answer (score 0):

In this case. You need to create `DataTemplate` inside `ListBox.ItemsSource`. Create a `TextBlock` and bind it to DeviceName.

Comment: it's too redundant for such simple case. See answer made by @tencntraze. he has mentioned **DisplayMemberPath**

Comment: Any suggestion with this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22051624/wpf-datagrid-selecteditems-not-working-on-production

Answer (score 0):

You also have to set the DataContext. Add "DataContext = this;" to the myControl constructor.
Or you could do it this way, without setting the DataContext

```
<ListBox Name="DeviceListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource
        FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Window}},Path=DeviceList}" DisplayMemberPath="DeviceName"/>
```